# Internet not working without preferred DNS server

Tags: dns

My machine is connected to the office net work using wifi. My internet was working for some time without any issue. Suddenly this morning the internet stopped working although I could ping to 8.8.8.8 and other network IPs. I set the preferred DNS server and the alternate DNS server and made it work again. My question is why was it working without these settings and why did I need to enter these settings suddenly? What changes did my computer go through without me doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Had the DNS on your machine been set before? If so,minor changes to a WIFI policy would then make your machine create a second WIFI network connection. This would then make your previously set DNS no longer valid.